# How can I get rid of the messages area in a Vuetify slider?

Tags: slider, vuetify.js

I'm using a `v-slider` in a Vuetify context. The component has a message area that takes some space below the slider and makes it impossible to align the actual slider (the "line") in the vertical center to line up with other neighbouring components.

There seems to be a number of way to customize the message, but how do I get rid of that area completely? There will never be any messages to display there.

I've now resorted to adding a padding on top of the slider, align the components and then add a negative top padding on the group. But that seems just like a hack that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the prop "hide-details" to the slider

```
<v-slider v-model="volume" label="Volume" hide-details></v-slider>
```

You can find all the possible props in the API-Section for the [sliders](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders#api).